# unable to download a file using ssl handshake via a url in nodejs

Tags: node.js, ssl-certificate, gnutls

I am trying to download a file using a url for that i need to do tls handshake as it is a https url this is the code i am working on but it is running but no result and error

my nodjs code

```
var https = require('https');
var fs = require('fs');
var tls= require('tls');
var options = {

  // These are necessary only if using the client certificate authentication (so yeah, you need them)
  key: fs.readFileSync('client-private-key.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('client-certificate.pem'),

  // This is necessary only if the server
   //uses the self-signed certificate
  ca: [ fs.readFileSync('certdata') ]


};


var socket = tls.connect(443, options, function() {
  console.log('client connected',
              socket.authorized ? 'authorized' : 'unauthorized');

   var file = fs.createWriteStream("file.xlsx");

   console.log('running');
 var request = http.get("https://example.com/secure/attachment/206906/fr-373_update.xlsx", function(response) {

  response.pipe(file);
});
    process.stdin.pipe(socket);
  process.stdin.resume();
});
socket.setEncoding('utf8');
socket.on('data', function(data) {
 console.log(data);
});
socket.on('end', function() {
  server.close();
});
```